# Jquery file upload plugin with php how to receive ajax data

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using [jQuery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

i have read all the docs provided. there is a php integration class but the class is so complicated and not commented at all i just want how to receive the JSON Data and response to the plugin.

because i want a simple implementation just receive the $_FILES array and upload files with move uploaded files. this is the simple plugin:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({

     dataType: 'json',
  done: function (e, data) {
      $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
        $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
      });
  }
});
```

and the html is:

```
   <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="server/php/" multiple>
```

the question is how to receive the $_FILES array from this plugin and response to it ???

please could someone help me?  just a simple code snippet and i will do the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, getting the data on the php-side:

This should be something like:

```
<?php
foreach( $_FILES as $f )
{
    echo "name = ".$f['name'][0]."\n";
    echo "type = ".$f['type'][0]."\n";
    echo "tmp_name = ".$f['tmp_name'][0]."\n";
    echo "error = ".$f['error'][0]."\n";
    echo "size = ".$f['size'][0]."\n";

}
?>
```

If it doesn't work (in your php handler):

```
# ...
error_log( print_r( $_REQUEST, true ) )
error_log( print_r( $_FILES, true ) )
# ...
```

The output is written to the error log of your server. It should look somewhat like:

```
# $_REQUEST
array(0) {
}

# $_FILES
array(1) {
  ["files"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(30) "some.pdf"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "application/pdf"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpkqOz2M"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(51869)
    }
  }
}
```

You will have to walk the array of $_FILES and move each one to where to store it...

```
foreach( $_FILES as $f ){
    move_uploaded_file( $f['tmp_name'][0], './some/path/'.$f['name'][0] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This PlugIn has some cool server-side code that already does the job of storing the files for you. You can override all the defaults defined in the [constructor](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php). Here is an example based on the bit too short [example](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/index.php) on the project page of this great plugin.

```
<?php
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler( array(
  'upload_dir' => dirname(__FILE__).'/files/',
  'accept_file_types' => '/(jpg|gif|txt)$/i',
) );
?>
```

This will accept all jpg, gif and txt files and store them to the "/files/" directory, which is a local path below the dir where this script resides in. But of course your could specify another path, as long as it is an absolute path. Maybe it will even work with relative paths.

Just override the options from line 39 - 107 of the [UploadHandler.php](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php) as you like.

Comment: actually i want to upload the files using my FTP Upload class that's why i want to know how this class works and gets data from the plugin